# HTML5, what's that all about then?

Tags: html

I've got plenty of experience in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, etc. but I've yet to make the plunge into HTML5.

In trying to get my head around HTML5, I've become a bit confused. So it's a relatively new standard and my uninformed brain tells me it's not well supported. Is this true?

I've got a vague idea that there are some 3rd party scripts that improve HTML5 compatibility, again am I right?

Any good tutorials on getting to grips with the basics of HTML5 for an experienced developer?

Comment: Vote to close??! One favourite and 3 answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a lot of questions there but:

1. HTML5 is quite well supported on most modern browsers nowadays and it's generally safe enought to use as is.
2. Scripts to improve compatibility? you mean Javascript that detects how old your browser is and depending on the answer show you HTML 4.01 or 5? well maybe but again, it's at the point when it is not required anymore.
3. Yes: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp) has a cool one.

All of that said bare in mind that HTML 5 is still in development and not a done deal. Some areas are still being implemented but at the speed things are take this is not an issue for starting to develop your pages in HTML 5.

[This website - html5 doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) is a very usefull resource that you can browse looking for what's implemented where and how things are generally going.

I also found this [link](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#html5-web-applications) to be particularly useful when figuring out what's available for each browser and what's not.

Another subject that goes well with HTML5 is CSS3. Check them both out and maybe come back with specific questions ;)

Comment: Cheers, is a bit vague but I wanted a starting point and looking things up tended to jump to specifics. Ta!

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 support is not yet fully integrated in all browsers. They are still in development stage. For studying the HTML 5 the best medium would be [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp)

They have introduced new elements in HTML5 which has reduced our overhead for html. [New Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)

[CodePlayer](http://thecodeplayer.com/)

[Videos for HTML 5](http://www.web3mantra.com/2011/06/24/20-html5-video-tutorials/)

Comment: Offtopic, does anyone else absolutely HATE w3schools for it's utter uselessness? Easily the worst learning resource on the web. (don't take it personal Shivkant, your post was ok!)

Comment: @Rodik : w3schools may not be good in example, but he has all the details related to html5 and other stuff too. yet more new elements are to be introduced in HTML5 and w3schools is first to publicly present the html5 and also updating it. So, for atleast what new things are arrived can be found here ... :)

Answer (score 1):

the HTML5 buzzword is being used a lot, but people mostly use it to describe different things.

HTML5 is the newest (and as of yet, unfinished) iteration of the HTML standard, as presented by W3.org.

Purely, HTML5 is the markup language, but it is usually referred to as to include CSS3, and JS (in the form of the canvas element).

In the HTML area, HTML5 boasts some new element tags that should help developers add semantic meaning to their markups(e.g. [header](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/header), [footer](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/footer), [aside](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside)) , and also some useful functional elements ([progress-bar](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/progress), [video](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video), [audio](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio))

In the CSS area, there are some new properties that allow you to animate your elements, and orient them more easily.

In the JS area, you can read up on the Canvas element, which is a good competitor to Flash. It allows you to draw both using vectors, and bitmap data.

As for good references to HTML5, you can use http://html5doctor.com/ or http://www.html5rocks.com/en/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that w3schools isn't such a good reference anymore. Although for just looking at the possibilities it's fine I guess.

I recommend the **tutorial** from [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/HTML5-for-Flash-Developers/97148-2.html), but there are other sites. Just search at google. It's also possible to buy a book, since there have been written a few already.

**Fallback/polyfill** Scripts & libraries like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/),[Javascript Libraries](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/05/17/cross-browser-styling-of-html5-forms-even-in-older-browsers/) can help you take care of older browsers. (backwards compatible)

As for the **browsers**. Use chrome, it supports most of the functions. Look at sites like [findmebyip](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#target-selector#nav-access) for more information about what is supported.